# refrence wordpress form filed to another entity

Tags: wordpress, formbuilder

Does WordPress have any kind of form builder that can integrate forms and create relationship between difference form.
for sample a field data can be selected from another form or entity and reference to another form.

i tried wpform and Advanced Forms for ACF ,but its just simple form builder that create individual forms.

i work with Drupal before and we have node reference filed type that can be easily reference to other node content or user,therefore when user want to fill this filed system automatically list all data from referenced entity.